# What causes this Node/Postgres FATAL Error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Any help would be appreciated...
Not sure why I get this error every now and then. I've search off and on for a solution but keep coming up empty.
I run my Node App as a service on Centos7. It can run for a few days ... or even a month before getting this error.
I use a Pooled connection to Postgres and am inserting data into several different databases every few seconds.

```
events.js:377
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
error: terminating connection due to administrator command
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
at Parser.parse (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
at Client._handleErrorEvent (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:319:10)
at Client._handleErrorMessage (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:330:12)
at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)
at /home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12
at Parser.parse (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/beenth12/public_html/ws/wxbox/node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) {
length: 116,
severity: 'FATAL',
code: '57P01',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'postgres.c',
line: '3193',
routine: 'ProcessInterrupts'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) will inform you that SQLSTATE 57P01 is `admin_shutdown`. So somebody shutdown the database, and it is not surprising that your database connection got terminated.

Comment: That's just it... there is no evidence of ANYONE shutting down the database. I totally understand what you are saying... but I cannot find out when/who/where this is happening.
Is there anyplace I can check? Logs? etc?

Comment: Yes, the PostgreSQL server log.